# Updating a SharePoint list using export-spweb powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, sharepoint-server, export

I have a list in two different sites. 
Those lists data has to be in sync. 
But somehow my content guys forgot to do that. 
What happens when i import the list from one site to another site which already have the same list with same name and content type. 
Will it replace the lists or Update the items which has different data and add the items which are not present. 
I have just did a import

```
Import-SPWeb -Identity "http://mydestinationsite" -Path "C:\Backup\destinationslist.cmp"
```

I am worried as we have workflow attached to the lists is it going to remove the workflow.

any guidance

Answer (score 0):

When you import the list content,  it will add a new row with same information, It has happened to me many times.

Comment: SUDHIR SOMEHOW IT IS true as well. but it my case i have a difference experience. I got my current list items overwritten which only updated the modified date and added new items which doesn't exist. I have same list with same name and datatypes from long time so i hope that might be a difference. but if i create a brand new list and do the export again at that time it appended the items to duplicate.